# implementing fix for multiple markers on same location Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a site based on open data financial data sets which I have begun mapping with the Google Maps JavaScript API. I don't normally do JavaScript but managed to get basic maps running of user input ([Example](https://goo.gl/x2GudQ)).

The only problem with this is that where there are multiple markers on the same postcode only one marker is shown regardless of zoom.

I am trying to implement one  of the fixes either Spiderfy or to use JS to [slightly alter the lat & lon](http://www.frontendfan.com/multiple-markers-with-the-exact-same-location/) where there is more than one instance in the array. The latter approach looks easiest for me, but I could do with some help integrating it with my existing script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {lat: -19.5541589, lng: 145.7731922}

                         });

      setMarkers(map);
    }

    // Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
    // order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
    var recipientes = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]

    ];

    function setMarkers(map) {
      // Adds markers to the map.

      // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
      // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

      // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
      // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
      var image = {
        url: 'https://openaus.net.au/scripts/images/Flag1-orange-icon.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 22),
        // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 22)
                  };
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
      // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
      // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
      var shape = {
        coords: [1, 1, 1, 40, 36, 40, 36, 1],
        type: 'poly'
                  };
      for (var i = 0; i < recipientes.length; i++) {
        var recipient = recipientes[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: recipient[1], lng: recipient[2]},
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          shape: shape,
          title: recipient[0],
          zIndex: recipient[3]
                       });
      }

    }
        </script>
        <script async defer
          src="API key">
        </script>
```

I don't know how to change the solution to work with my existing code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {lat: -19.5541589, lng: 145.7731922}

                         });

      setMarkers(map);
    }

    // Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
    // order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
    var recipientes = [
     ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]

    ];

    function setMarkers(map) {
      // Adds markers to the map.

      // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
      // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

      // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
      // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
      var image = {
        url: 'https://openaus.net.au/scripts/images/Flag1-orange-icon.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 22),
        // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 22)
                  };
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
      // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
      // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
      var shape = {
        coords: [1, 1, 1, 40, 36, 40, 36, 1],
        type: 'poly'
                  };
      for (var i = 0; i < recipientes.length; i++) {
        var recipient = recipientes[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: recipient[1], lng: recipient[2]},
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          shape: shape,
          title: recipient[0],
          zIndex: recipient[3]
                       });
      }

    }

    //get array of markers currently in cluster
    var allMarkers = namespace.mapParams.mapMarkersArray;

    //final position for marker, could be updated if another marker already exists in same position
    var finalLatLng = latlng;

    //check to see if any of the existing markers match the latlng of the new marker
    if (allMarkers.length != 0) {
        for (i=0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
            var existingMarker = allMarkers[i];
            var pos = existingMarker.getPosition();

            //if a marker already exists in the same position as this marker
            if (latlng.equals(pos)) {
                //update the position of the coincident marker by applying a small multipler to its coordinates
                var newLat = latlng.lat() + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500;// * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                var newLng = latlng.lng() + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500;// * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                finalLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);
            }
        }
    }

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: msf_namespace.mapParams.resultmap,
        position: finalLatLng,
        title: name,
        icon: markericon
    });
    //add each generated marker to mapMarkersArray
    namespace.mapParams.mapMarkersArray.push(marker);
        </script>
        <script async defer
          src="API key">
        </script>
```

If someone could help me figure it out I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: might consider using markerCluster plugin